# Django: how can I update more than one record at once?

Tags: python, django

How can I update multiple records in a queryset efficiently?

Do I just loop over the queryset, edit , and call `save()` for each one of them? Is it equivalent to psycopg2's `executemany`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have to update each record with a different value, then of couse you have to iterate over each record. If you wish to do update them all with the same value, then just use the update method of the queryset.

Comment: @goh I can't say 100%, but I would be very surprised if it was. Since you're calling save after modifying each record, there's no chance for the backend to know that they should be batched. There may be a way of doing so, but the direct queryset/model api shouldn't do it in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the queryset update method. Here's the documentation:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update

If you look at the code, it does loop over the items. In fact this is what Django admin uses when doing "bulk" actions on items.

Comment: @lee, I'm not sure if i can use update. Different records have different updated values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QuerySet's [bulk_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update)

Example:

```
YourModel.objects.bulk_update(queryset_or_list_of_objs, ["field1", "field2", ...])
```